# How can I send ether between two ACCOUNTS in remix IDE?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, send, remix

I can only send the ether if I deposit the ether while creating the contract. But in this case, even if the ether is in my wallet, I can send as much ether as the amount of ether in the contract. For example: 
I have 100 ethereum in my account and I used 10 ether while creating smart contract, but I have to send 15 ether to other account. But I can't send because it is more than the amount of ether contract. I need to send ether to other account from my wallet.

Environment is Remix IDE, Contract versions is 
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

```
    function payBack (address payable user) public payable returns(bool) {
        uint256 money =  balanceOf(user)*convertNumber/1e18;

        require (msg.sender.balance/1e18 > money, "not enough money" );
        user.send(money*1000000000000000000);
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

If you're using https://remix.ethereum.org you can see the "Environment" in the top right hand corner of the IDE.

According to the docs:

> There are 3 type of environments Remix can be plugged to: Javascript VM, Injected provider, or Web3 provider. (for details see Running transactions)

These three environments are:

The **JavascriptVM** is running a sandboxed blockchain in your browser where execution runs in your browser. This means you don’t need any other software or Ethereum node to run it. *This makes it very simple to deploy contract and interact with contracts limits your ability to manage account*

The **Web3 provider** will make remix connect to a remote node. You will need to provide the URL address to the selected provider: geth, parity or any Ethereum client. You can use a tool like [`ganache-cli`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) which simulates a blockchain locally on your computer as well.

The **Injected Provider** will make remix connect to an injected web3 provider. Metamask is an example of providers that inject web3, thus can be used with this option.

[See docs](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html?highlight=run%20tab) for more information about environments.

I'm going to guess you're using the *JavaScriptVM* environment which means, unfortunately, you won't have access to `web3` command tools (which need Web3 Provider or Injection). Without web3 you can't move funds between accounts by constructing transactions.

What you can do is download `ganache-cli` or your favourite web3 provider, and manipulate accounts from the terminal using web3 commands.

For example:

```
   $ ganache-cli 

Available Accounts <ADDRESSES YOU CAN MOVE FUNDS BETWEEN>
==================
(0) 0x9f0bf61721a61e7f72abac48eed65e318668e71f (~100 ETH)
(1) 0x74bc67c48eefc359d296023acd4ac9158575ab56 (~100 ETH)
(2) 0xec548e4b5246795b81904bc67cedfe26b528b173 (~100 ETH)
(3) 0x06fe6ca72d985252729a2ba2a40147d4905a56c4 (~100 ETH)
(4) 0x262498200090fdaa7db8d430e681e39d6257d3ce (~100 ETH)
(5) 0x9736aa7dc69bee01166352c3e51023ee5ab57a08 (~100 ETH)
(6) 0x19ee475e3c64935546d9c4a67d01232c53d45c2b (~100 ETH)
(7) 0xee4dec500f7b08dfe20646a8a6661a81204eb1cb (~100 ETH)
(8) 0xf5b6a5ce718ad527eb877a0c8554e1d2382c9beb (~100 ETH)
(9) 0x590e03591cc82e9308d1e8e8869c248e13356920 (~100 ETH)

<Secret private keys not shown >

HD Wallet
==================
<Mnemonics not shown >

Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Gas Price
==================
20000000000

Gas Limit
==================
6721975

Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, Now i am using ganache-cli and my current environment is web3 provider. But still i can send ether as much as value of "value field" (top and right under gas limit ). Also I tried to use metamask using Mnemonic of local test blockchain.

if i understood correctly, your suggestion is that `web3.sendTransaction({to:receiver, from:sender, value:web3.toWei("0.5", "ether")})`
Is there any way to do this in Remix IDE

Comment: have you tried address.send(amount) or address.transfer(amount) method? you have to convert ethers into wei first with uint256 amount = 0.5 * 1 ether then send to payable address